# How to multiple all digits of x number?

Tags: c#

I'm doing a counting program and i need to multiple all digits of x number by it self.

for example: number 123456789;

1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9=362,880

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Hi Devi, welcome to SO!  What have you tried so far?

Comment: How much do you know about `for` loops? or `foreach`, or linq?

Comment: `123456789.ToString().Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9').Select(c => c - '0').Aggregate(1, (s, v) => s * v)`

Comment: @MatthewWhited if your input is a positive integer you do not need `Where`, so it can be written even simpler `123.ToString().Aggregate(1, (c, n) => c * (n - '0'))`. It looks like we just did someone homework for free :)

Comment: yeah, I filtered to make sure it was only numbers. And to be fair if any digit is 0 the final result will be 0;

Comment: another way if you don't want to convert to strings `var num = 123456789; var result = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(num))).Aggregate(1, (v, d) => v * ((num / (int)Math.Pow(10, d)) % 10));`

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is provided in the comments, but it isn't very easy to follow if you are trying to figure out what you are *actually* doing.  The following code is a bit more verbose, but shows you what is actually happening each step of the way:

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main () {
    int myNumber = 123456789;  //store original number
    int newNumber = (int)Math.Abs(myNumber);  //changes the number to positive if it is negative to prevent string formatting errors.
    int product = 1; //store product start point
    string myString = newNumber.ToString(); //convert number to string

    foreach(char number in myString){  //loop through string
      string numberString = number.ToString();  //convert chars to strings to ensure proper output
      int oneDigit = Convert.ToInt32(numberString); //convert strings to integers
      product = product*oneDigit;  //multiply each integer by the product and set that as the new product
    }
    if(myNumber < 0){product = -product;} 
    //if the number is negative, the result will be negative, since it is a negative followed by a bunch of positives.
    //If you want your result to reflect that, add the above line to account for negative numbers.
    Console.WriteLine(product);  //display product
  }
}

Output>>> 362880  //The output that was printed.
```

So we start by converting our number into a string so we can iterate through it.  Then we have a `foreach` loop that goes through each character in the string, converts it into an integer, and multiplies it by the product of the previous numbers.  Each time a new multiplication is performed, the product is updated, until, when you reach the end of the number, you have the product of all digits.  This is a good project to become familiar with looping. I would recommend playing around with variations of it such as multiplying each number by the original number, multiplying together only multiples of 3, only multiplying numbers less than 5, or only multiplying the first 5 numbers to get a better handle on what's happening in a loop.

Comment: Just in case original number is below zero, you need to add something like `myNumber = (int)Math.Abs(myNumber);` before getting `myString`. If you skip this you will have troubles with converting `-` to int

Comment: True, but when answering simple questions like this I tend not to bother with full coverage.  A production-quality answer was already provided in the comments.  I wanted to provide something that would lay out, in a way that is simple to understand, the basic logic that goes into working out a problem like this.  Adding extra logic to it to cover additional use cases bogs down the core explanation of what is occurring, which I think is important not to do when someone is just starting out.  Dealing with negative numbers is a good addition to the "things to try" list for the questioner.

Comment: The questioner is clearly learning to program.  Rather than giving him something easy to copy and paste into otherwise already working production code, as one would with a professional programmer, I think it's best to go back to basics and just focus on what loops are and how they are used.

Comment: I've understood your point and upvoted your answer, you did a good job, you are awesome ... and so on. I've leave my comment because I almost sure that tomorrow I will see question like _I want to multiply digits in `-123` and it throws me  `FormatException`_

Comment: Point taken.  I'll update it now.  I mostly didn't want to deal with it because I didn't want to add another if statement to add the minus sign if the product were negative.  If I start refactoring my OCD almost inevitably kicks in.